# How to import csv and save in MSSQL database using golang?

Tags: sql-server, go

This is my code. Currently, I just read the contents of the CSV file. I need to migrate this CSV file to MSSQL using Go Language Application

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    rows := readOrders("Ec2Instances.csv")
}

func readOrders(name string) [][]string {
    f, err := os.Open(name)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Cannot open '%s': %s\n", name, err.Error())
    }
    defer f.Close()
    r := csv.NewReader(f)
    r.Comma = ';'
    rows, err := r.ReadAll()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Cannot read CSV data:", err.Error())
    }
    return rows
}
```

I want the CSV file to be written specifically into the "MSSQL Database". I have installed MSSQL and SSMS Softwares. How do I access these and write data into it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're half way there!

Your sample code looks like it will read CSV data from a named file. The next step would be to connect to the MSSQL database instance and insert the rows from the CSV data.

To do so, you'll need to find a golang driver for that database ([`denisenkom/go-mssqldb`](https://github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb) looks worth trying, there's even a [simple example](https://github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb/blob/master/examples/simple/simple.go)) and follow the patterns established by the [go `database/sql` package](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/) (especially the [package examples](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#pkg-examples)).

A working solution might look something like this (not working but demonstrative):

```
import (
  "database/sql"
  _ "github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb"
  // ...
)

func main() {
  rows := readOrders("Ec2Instances.csv")
  insertRowsToDatabase(rows)
}

func insertRowsToDatabase(rows [][]string) {
  // Connect to the database.
  connString := "server=myserver;user id=123;password=secret;port=234"
  db, err := sql.Open("mssql", connString)
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("Open connection failed:", err.Error())
  }
  defer db.Close()

  // Insert the rows, omitting the first header row from the CSV.
  stmt, err := db.Prepare("INSERT INTO Ec2Instances(id, name) VALUES(?, ?)")
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }
  for _, row := range rows[1:] {
    _, err := stmt.Exec(row[0], row[1])
    if err != nil {
      log.Fatal(err)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. So here we have a for loop for 21 columns . So can you please elaborate on how to add the "stmt,Exec()" . I am quite new to golang so can you please walk me through the for loop .

Comment: You can find plenty of online documentation about [for-loops](https://gobyexample.com/for) and [`sql.Stmt.Exec`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Stmt.Exec). Good luck!